# count words in a file without using wc

Tags: shell, unix

Working in a shell script here, trying to count the number of words/characters/lines in a file without using the wc command.  I can get the file broken into lines and count those easy enough, but I'm struggling here to get the words and the characters.

```
#define word_count function
count_stuff(){
    c=0
    w=0
    l=0
    local f="$1"
    while read Line
    do
        l=`expr $line + 1`
        # now that I have a line I want to break it into words and characters???
    done < "$f"
    echo "Number characters:  $chars"
    echo "Number words: $words"
    echo "Number lines: $line"
```

}

Comment: `tr -s ' \t\r\n' '\n'` may be helpful.

Comment: Why don't you want to use wc? It's available virtually everywhere.

Comment: take a look at [this](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/3783/implement-wc-word-count-shortest-code-wins/4571)

Comment: Are you using bash? kev has pointed at a good resource for other implementations. Bash is not the best alternative here. You can hardly make sure it works in all cases. For example read by default allows escaping end of line with a backslash '\'. So you need to do `read -r`. `read -N` can be used with better success tracking newlines if you need portability (mac or windows). FYI `${#parameter}` gives you number of chars in a variable in bash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As for characters, try this (adjust echo "test" to where you get your output from):

```
expr `echo "test" | sed "s/./ + 1/g;s/^/0/"`
```

As for lines, try this:

```
expr `echo -e "test\ntest\ntest" | sed "s/^.*$/./" | tr -d "\n" | sed "s/./ + 1/g;s/^/0/"`
```

===

As for your code, you want something like this to count words (if you want to go at it completely raw):

```
while read line ; do
 set $line ;
 while true ; do
  [ -z $1 ] && break
  l=`expr $l + 1`
  shift ;
 done ;
done
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the following Bash shell script:

```
count=0
for var in `cat $1`
do
    count=`echo $count+1 | bc`
done
echo $count
```